# Improving semantic interpretation of dates

Tags: date-and-time, interpreter

`SemanticInterpretation` and `Interpreter` are promising but imperfect, eg extracting dates and calendar expressions from semi-structured documents.

Consider this sample of 92 items extracted from legal documents by a team at USDOJ which develops regex: dates are a major challenge.

```
doj92[0] = {"February 2006","July 2006 - December 2006","December, 2006","2/1/07 - 2/28/07","Jan. 1-31, 2007","February 1-28, 2007","1/1/07 through 1/31/07","01-31-07","DECEMBER 1 TO DECEMBER 31, 2007","DECEMBER 30, 2006 TO JANUARY 31, 2007","Jan/Feb 2007","Mar. 21 through 31, 2007","Jan 3, 2007","First Quarter 2007","Nov & Dec 2006","DECEMBER ----- 2006","JANUARY -- 2007","March-2007","11/2007","7/07","12-06","JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER-2006","3/1/07 to 3/31/07","July 1, 2006 - Sept. 30, 2006","Oct. 1,2006 - Dec. 31,2006","Jan 1, 2003 - Mar 31, 2003","May 1 2007 To May 31 2007","APRIL 16TH, THROUGH APRIL 30TH, 2007","May 9th, through May 31st, 2007","May 31,07","Month of July","(Month Ending)August","July 2006, August 2006 and April 2007","Aug. 1 Through Aug. 31, 2007","8/1/ 07 - 8/31/ 07","May 30 - June 2007","6/1/30/2007 to 6/30/2007","080107 - 083107","Januanry 1, 2007 - Janurary 31, 2007","June 1, 2007 - June 31, 2007","September 31, 2007","September2007","Sep 07","July 20--31, 2007","August (2007) ","09 01 07 to 09 30 07","04-16-07/09-30-07","October, 2006 and February, 2007","5/25 - 5/31 2007 May","6/1 -6/30 2007","Sept.30,2007","Sept. 19 - Sept. 30","May 30 - June 2007","October 1st to October 9th","10/31/'07","8/9/078/31/07","10/1-07-10/31/07","11//14/07","10/1/7 to 10/31/7","Octobeer 2007","Seotember 2007","Septmber 2007","September 1, 2007 to Setember 30, 2007","July through September 2007 ","3Q07","0/30/2007","Augusut 2007","September, 30 2006","3rdQuater,2007","Beginning 08012007 and Ending 08312007","4th Quarterly Report 2006","Beginning 110107 and Ending 113007","10/01/07 to 10/310/07","JULY, AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTUBER 2007","11.07","Nov.2007","Novermber 2007","November 15, 2007 to Decmeber 15, 2007","093007 ","Novemer 2007","December 1, to 31, 2007","December 1,2007 through Deceber 31, 2007","Decmber 2007","DCEMBER 2008","12/1-31/07","Beginning 10/1/2007 and Ending 10/31/2007","Third Qtr 2007","November 2007, December 2007 & January 2008","12/01/207 to 12/31/2007","October 2007 - December 2007","January 16th through 31st, 2008","010108 to 013108"}//MapIndexed[<|"num"-> First@#2,"text"->  #1|>&]//Dataset;
```

Comparison table shown as compact screenshots:

```
doj92[1] = 
  doj92[0][All, 
   Append[#, <| "SemanticInterp" -> SemanticInterpretation[#text], 
      "Interp/Date" ->  Interpreter["Date"][#text], 
      "Interp/Computed" -> Interpreter["ComputedDate"][#text]|>] &];
```

Although `SemanticInterpretation` works better than `Interpreter` and even `Interpreter` notably on calendar expressions that yield date intervals, it fails or yields incorrect ambiguous interpretations for 42 (46%) items:

```
doj92[1][{11, 15, 16, 17, 19, 20, 21, 22, 28, 29, 31, 32, 33, 36, 37, 
  38, 41, 43, 44, 47, 48, 49, 56, 57, 58, 59, 65, 66, 69, 70, 71, 72, 
  73, 74, 75, 79, 81, 85, 86, 88, 91, 92}]
```

[image]
[image][image]

This small scale test based on real world data shows that significant pre-processing/normalization of the text is needed. `Interpreter` does accept pattern matching options, but its fail rate is much higher (with a few exceptions like #19-21).

Are there some basic pre-processing or options for these method that could improve performance and generalize? Or are large-scale tests needed to validate these tools?