# Convert .csv Dataset and store in Databin

Tags: export, dataset, wolfram-cloud

Trying out the new Databin product in the Wolfram Cloud.

I have a simple ,-delimited .csv file with a header row which I have imported using the follwing:

```
apps = SemanticImport["ListOfAppsWithAttributes.csv", Automatic, "Dataset", HeaderLines ->1]
```

Simple calls such as `apps[Total, "StorageDemand"]` work just fine.

I would now like to export/write this dataset to the Databin.

```
theBin = CreateDatabin[]
Export[theBin,apps]
```

However I get the following error:

> Export:chtype: First argument Databin[...] is not a valid file
>   specification.

Also, using `DatabinAdd[theBin, apps]` will also throw an error:

> Databin:apperr: An API must be specified.

Any suggestions on how to export/write a dataset to a databin in a short/direct way?

**-------- EDIT (post 'on hold' decision) --------**

*This is to share the outcome of a follow-up investigation on the topic.*

> Dislaimer: Wolfram's DataDrop and with it the Databin command as part
>   of the Wolfram Language are being pushed as extensions of Mathematica.
>   Hence the posting in this forum.

Analysis:

the issues I have encountered where with

1. the dataset's cleanliness
2. the need to RTFM on setting adequate parameters for SemanticImport to begin with, and
3. also some other (c) observations worth sharing around the 'behaviour' of the Databin interface.

The dataset:

- ~2900 rows with approx 100 columns.
- Originally managed in Excel, then exported to .csv Many cells had ',' in them which had to be cleaned up. Not doing so skewed the loads drastically and obviously produces the wrong outcome.
- Several cells had UTF-8 characters in it which created additional noise.

The code which worked in principle after fixing the file:

```
apps = SemanticImport["DataFilesFullset/Index_AllRows_AllColumns.csv", Automatic, "Dataset", Delimiters -> ",", HeaderLines ->1, CharacterEncoding -> "ASCII"];
theBin = CreateDatabin[]
For[i = 1, i< 2000, i++, DatabinAdd[theBin,apps[i]]]
```

The for loop was inserted to ensure that the size limit on Databin items (25kb by default) is not exceeded.

Additional points to note though on the loading of the Dataset subsequently into the Databin. The DataDrop platform enforces ingestion and compute ceilings which you may need to take note of when attempting to load 'lots' of data in relatively short time.

[image]

I hope this additional info is useful for future readers of this page. The question as such though should be closed.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post your data, for example at a site like [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), so others can download it and test possible solutions.

Comment: Will have to do some obfuscation before I upload publicly. But just imagine a very simple comma-delimited file: 1 st record: HeaderField1,HeaderField2... then 2nd record etc: 1234,AppName

Comment: A minimal set of fake data is probably fine as long as it has the same structure. I guess I assumed you already had a set of toy data that you were using to test things.

Comment: Have you tried to use [`DatabinUpload`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DatabinUpload.html)? Although the docs for DatabinAdd mention that the added expression can be anything, the examples only show adding a single data point or an association. I also couldn't find a definitive reference showing that one can use `Export` with a `Databin` object.

Comment: Tried the `DatabinUpload[theBin, apps]`, but it throws and error: _DatabinUpload::uplist: The data entries should be a list or an EventSeries_

Comment: I created a CSV file, imported it using your command and obtained a working dataset, then created a bin. I first tried Export, to confirm that it won't work, but that was expected, because it does not support Dataset objects. I then used `DatabinAdd` to add the contents of my dataset to the bin, using your syntax. **It worked fine, so I can't seem to reproduce your error**, so the problem either resides in your data (which you are not willing to share) or in some configuration issue on your side, which may be best resolved by contacting WRI support.

Comment: @MarcoB thanks for that. I have since created the trival .csv as well and indeed it works with the `DatabinAdd[theBin, apps]` code I used. Will do some investigation on the actual dataset at hand to see what causes the error.

Comment: Good to know, in a way. I'm voting to close this question. Maybe you can come back with another question when you are able to pinpoint the underlying problem with your dataset.

Comment: @MarcoB Agreed - digging through it right now

Comment: @ElArchitect, Re `SemanticImport` and related functions are not ready for prime time, nor do most M.SE users seem to consider them part Mathematic: eg I asked how to improve performance on recognizing dates from contracts, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79241/improving-semantic-interpretation-of-dates, you can see by the votes how popular.