# How to extract "this text" between specific characters: 1) this text 1)

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a text file that has thousands of questions and blanks for the answer, like this:

1) This is the first question         1)______

2) This is the second question        2)______

3)...

What I want to do is to extract the questions, and put them in a spreadsheet (I'm going to end up putting them in a database). I tried reading through Mathematica's [Working with Strings](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html) page, but I couldn't figure out how to do it! Can someone please let me know how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll use a slightly modified example:

```
str = "1) This is the first question 1)______

 2) This is the second question 2)______

 ...

 10) This is the tenth question 10)______"
```

One can use either `StringExpression[]` or `RegularExpression[]` in `StringCases[]` for this; here's how:

```
StringTrim /@ StringCases[str,
                          n : DigitCharacter .. ~~ ")" ~~ s__ ~~ n_ ~~ ")" :> s]
```

or

```
StringTrim /@ StringCases[str, RegularExpression["(\\d+\\))(.+)\\1"] -> "$2"]
```

which should both yield `{"This is the first question", "This is the second question", "This is the tenth question"}`.

Comment: I wonder why people insist on hammering a screw and screwing a text processing problem

Comment: Could've been worse; at least it wasn't parsing XML with regex.

Comment: Thank you very much, the "RegularExpression" version that you posted ended up working really well for me (I actually have answer options in between the numbered problems).  Can you break down the solution for me? It just looks like some mumbo-jumbo inside RegularExpression. I know there are special character codes from Perl right?  Also, @belisariushassettled, do you have a suggestion for a better program/language to do text processing like this?

Comment: @NicolasJosephScozzaro Of course. I'm really glad you asked. For example, the unix-born text processing programs (now available on almost every platform) `perl`, `awk` or `sed`  are much better suited for these tasks than Mathematica. Your problem is a one liner in any of them. In particular you're up and running in `awk` in -perhaps- one to three hours depending on your background, and it is a very nice language to learn

Comment: @Nicolas, FWIW, the regex in *Mathematica* is PCRE, so you should be able to use it in Perl as well.

Comment: In the interest of teaching you how to fish, I'll separate the important components with spaces: `"( \\d+ \\) ) (.+) \\1"` and recall that backslashes have to be escaped in *Mathematica*, so the actual regex is more like `"( \d+ \) ) (.+) \1"`. You'll want to look up the following in a regex table: `\d`, `+`, `.`, and `\1`.

Comment: @NicolasJosephScozzaro: There are great websites like [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/gQ5wX6/2), where you can test regular expressions online. If you plan to do a lot of text processing, do yourself a favor and google for tutorials about regular expressions. They're not hard to use, and make text processing so much easier...

Comment: @belisariushassettled, the Mathematica code at least in this answer is also a one-liner - can you give examples of one-liners in the Unix tools that take a lot more effort in M?

Comment: @alancalvitti some very basic awk complete program examples [here](http://sparky.rice.edu/~hartigan/awk.html). I've made huge language conversion tools with it. Very easy to maintain ... perhaps somewhat difficult to debug

Comment: @bel, "somewhat difficult to debug" - I've been using regexes (`awk`, then `perl`) for years and I still have to look up stuff every so often. :D

Comment: @J.M. My worse experience is trying to understand what was I trying to do with a regex six months after writing it. But that happens to me with my Mma modules too. Each time I wrote `(* then trivially .... *)` I know for sure I shall blame myself in a near future

Comment: @belisariushassettled, many queries I wrote that were 1/2 page in V9 are now 1-5 lines w/ V10 features like `Association`, `Dataset`, `Query` etc. So why not identify common regex patterns and propose them for integration in future WL versions?

Comment: @alan, "identify common regex patterns" - it's already PCRE; I'm sure all of the useful patterns are already there.

Comment: @J.M., first of all, even that's a moving target: "You should treat [PCRE2] as a new project, not just a drastic update to PCRE1." -- Philip Hazel. But what I meant has less to do with PCRE than to factor the more difficult regex, just as M now has `Interpreter["Date"]`, though currently of poor accuracy: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/79241/improving-semantic-interpretation-of-dates